# Bamboo: current date in maven build-war params

Tags: maven, variables, continuous-integration, bamboo

I tried to append the current date to my build number with

```
-Dversion.buildnumber=${bamboo.current_date}
```

where `current_date = $(date+"%%m%%d%%H%%M")` (set in plan variables), but it doesn't work. I also tried to add

```
export BAMBOO_CURR_DATE=$(date +"%m%d%H%M")
```

and set `current_date=$BAMBOO_CURR_DATE` in plan vars. However, it return just `"$BAMBOO_CURR_DATE"` in the app version.

How can I get the formatted time in my app version?

Comment: correct code formatting, improve grammar

Comment: Sadly this is currently not possible but there is an improvement request: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-11636